# dhclient exit hook cannot write to directory

Tags: shell-script, rhel, dhclient

I am using RHEL 8.9 and have created a basic `dhclient` hook script in which I want to log to a file.

The script is able to write to places like `/tmp`, but not `/opt`. It can *read* files from `/opt`, but not write to the directory:

```shellsession
[root@server]# ls -la /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 159 Feb 12 22:47 /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/test.sh

[root@server]# cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/test.sh
#!/bin/bash
{ date; cat /opt/test1.txt; } >> /tmp/test1.txt # works as expected (reading from /opt and writing to /tmp)
date >> /opt/test2.txt # does not work; cannot write to /opt
```

When testing the hook I am seeing permission issues:

```shellsession
[root@server]# dhclient eth0
/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/test.sh: line 3: /opt/test2.txt: Permission denied
```

I have verified that write access is granted on the file in `/opt`, and even gone so far as to give write/execute to all users on the directory:

```shellsession
[root@server]# ls -la /opt/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root  40 Feb 12 22:46 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root root 224 Dec 21 10:37 ..
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root   4 Feb 12 22:45 test1.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root   4 Feb 12 22:46 test2.txt
```

File reading/writing to `/tmp` is working without issues.

I also can run the script directly with root and not face any permission issues (it works as expected).

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you use `dhclient -nc eth0`? According to the [die.net man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient), `dhclient` drops capabilities by default if it's built with libcap-ng support, which I'm guessing is likely the case for most distros.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am seeing the same result if running `dhclient -nc eth0` (permission issues).